# Where are the full refs for getstream.io REST api?

Tags: php, getstream-io

I've been implementing PHP getstream.io support for our app, found that the official PHP library is lacking compared to Python one.

Checking official api refs on getstream.io site - seems they are not full by any means as well.

For example - we have 'stats/follow/' endpoint, allowing to get following/followers counts easily, quite a common thing to use for user profiles. I found it by reading python lib. But it is not documented at all on the official site, there are no mentions it even exists.

Am I looking for the full api refs in the wrong place (on getstream.io official site)?
Maybe there are a lot of other useful endpoints I am not aware of, as they are not present in the official refs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stats/follow` is a recent addition (beta right now) which isn't added to PHP SDK at the moment. PRs are always welcome (good to imitate Python SDK). Anyway, it will be added though, just a matter of time.

REST docs will be auto generated in near future.

Comment: Thank you for answering. May I also ask if there are any undocumented endpoints allowing to get reaction count for specific activity? Right now we need to actually get all reactions and count them manually, which is total overkill if we need just to show reaction amount. Example - amount of likes or amount of comments per activity.

Comment: Add `withReactionCounts` query param while reading enriched activity